# Problem with mechanical Rigging

Tags: rigging

How can I Rig these Bones that they stay in the axises of the red dots but also rotate completly in the direction of the green arrow? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you don't tell enough. But if you want to only move the left big bone (bone1) so that the other ones follow you could use this setup:

- Give bone1 a *Limit Rotation* constraint so that it stays on its axis.
- Give bone2 a *Copy Rotation* so that it copies bone1's rotation.
- Give bone3 a *Track To* so that it keeps pointing at the tail fo bone2.
- Give bone4 a Copy Rotation so that it copies bone3 rotation.

[image]

Comment: This works fine thank you ,but only in Pose Mode. In the other Modes ( object and edit) the whole package of bones move together in one direction

Comment: i now used 2 different armatures and it works in object mode. now i want to parent the objects to the bones how do i do that right?

Comment: parent "With Empty Groups", then in Edit mode, assign vertices to the group they are supposed to be part of in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups

Comment: i now parentet the object to the bones but as soon as i assign vertices to the group the vertices rotate and distort?

Comment: You need to have your bones in rest pose when you parent (or select all your bones and alt R, alt G, alt S)

Comment: i tried the setup in a new project and it works really well thank you!

Answer (score 0):

one last question: if i want to build the object in the green circle to move in the direction of the arrow but still remains in the axis of the red dot what am i supposed to do?

[image]